# Can I remove "in" from this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence

> And Brandon wasn’t acting maliciously. Instead, he was complying with everything I asked of him, to the point that he was living out of a hotel despite having the legal right to reside with me here, **in** a house he apparently co-owned. If it were all some elaborate lie, then what was he gaining from it?

I don't know what "in" does in the sentence "in a house he apparently co-owned"

I think if I remove "in", the sentence is also correct.

Am I right? or it can't be deleted, because there is a function of "in"  I don't know.

EDIT: the source is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nosleep/comments/112j4ep/ever_since_i_woke_up_from_surgery_everyone_tells/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't be deleted. You reside (live) **in** a house. It's a very common function of 'in'.

I suppose it could be argued that *a house he apparently co-owned* defines *here*, but the sentence really would not sound natural with out the 'in'.

NB You really need to give the source of a sentence that you ask about.

Comment: so 
the part of the sentence should be.
"Despite having the legal right to reside `in a house he apparently co-owned` with me here."

since `reside in a house he apparently co-owned` is too long, so,the author just put it behind.

right ?

Comment: No, the sentence is fine as it is. The speaker says that Brandon has the right to live 'here' with her, and then adds the reason - that he part-owns the house.